# Rails ActiveRecord invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using MSSQL 2005.

I have **StringIO** object that contains my **zip** file content.

Here is how I obtain zip binary data:

```
    stringio = Zip::ZipOutputStream::write_buffer do |zio|
        Eclaim.find_by_sql("SET TEXTSIZE 67108864")
        zio.put_next_entry("application.xml")
        #zio.write @claim_db[:xml]
        biblio = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + @claim_db[:xml], &:noblanks)
        zio.write biblio.to_xml

        builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |xml|
            xml.documents {
                docs.where("ext not in (#{PROHIBITED_EXTS.collect{|v| "'#{v}'"}.join(', ')})").each{|doc|
                    zio.put_next_entry("#{doc[:materialtitle_id]}.#{doc[:ext]}")
                    zio.write doc[:efile]

                    xml.document(:id => doc[:materialtitle_id]) {
                        xml.title doc[:title]
                        xml.code doc[:code]
                        xml.filename "#{doc[:materialtitle_id]}.#{doc[:ext]}"
                        xml.extname doc[:ext]
                    }

                }
            }
        end

        zio.put_next_entry("docs.xml")
        zio.write builder.to_xml
    end

    stringio
```

In my **controller** I try:

```
data.rewind
@claim.docs.create(
    :title => 'Some file',
    :ext => 'zip',
    :size => data.length,
    :receive_date => Time.now,
    :efile => data.sysread
)
```

But Rails complains **invalid byte sequence in UTF-8**

Help me pls with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the stream is configured as UTF-8 stream, you can't write compressed binary (which may contain *any* value).

I think, setting `data` as binary stream before write:

```
data.force_encoding "ASCII-8BIT"
```

might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. That error was disappeared. But why when I write zip file to DB and then read it from DB to file system. That 2 files differ from each other in 1 byte. That one byte damages zip file ((

Comment: Besides rails, if we store binary, we usually store as varbinary or whatever type treat string as opaque data, which is different from printable string.

Rails, by default, treat string as printable string and maps to varchar, so unless you tweak Rails or migration, the string may be mapped to varchar. DB has default charset. And if the column is string (varchar) then it is natural to be treated as printable string when read into, cause encoding mapping to happen, which is UTF-8 in your case.

Answer (score 1):

What is complaining, ruby, ActiveRecord, or SQL Server?  My guess is SQL Server.  Make sure the data type of the efile field in the database is a binary BLOB.

Comment: I guess ActiveRecord complains. Maybe because of **data.sysread.encoding => #<Encoding:UTF-8>** but MSSQL stores blob in UTF-16

Answer (score 1):

You should break your problem down in constituate parts and troubleshoot smaller units. Remove complexity till you get to the source of the issue. For instance, have you tried just doing a simple `Document.create` with the attributes in say the console to remove the possibility that your controller code may be buggy? Something like `Document.create :efile => File.read('sometiny.zip')` and just go from there.

Assuming that works or break, you have a much simpler support request and less noise to issue ratio. Right now I suspect your controller code, not the  SQL Server Adapter or the connection mode, as I have both tested to the hilt for simple binary data. Assuming the above does not work, you can then moving to examining smaller components.

For instance, what is the data type of the `efile` column? Do this in the console to find out, `Document.columns_hash['efile']` and look at the `@sql_type`. Is it something suitable like `varbinary(max)`?

Moving on from there, what connection mode are you using with the SQL Server Adapter, TinyTDS? By default TinyTDS will convert everything to UTF8 as needed and is really smart about things. I have it tested with everything from binary to many different encodings. BTW, if you are using TinyTDS, did you make sure that you compiled FreeTDS with libiconv so it can do all this properly? You can easily check by doing the following in the console `tsql -C` assuming you have FreeTDS's binaries in your path. This should output a few lines, look for "iconv library: yes". Also make sure you are running 0.91 or better too!

Lastly, a bit of advice, that SET TEXTSIZE is so wrong there. You only want to do that once per connection. See here https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#configure-connection--app-name

Comment: Really thanks for help MetaSkills! First, I was tried **Document.create :efile => File.read('sometiny.zip')** in cosole but got the same error message. Second, eFile field has a datatype **image**. Third, I am using TinyTDS but under Windows. At last,  **data.force_encoding "ASCII-8BIT"** helped me but no quite (**But why when I write zip file to DB and then read it from DB to file system. That 2 files differ from each other in 1 byte**). it's strange